# Open an APK file on a Mac?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I just built an appp in phone gap build i'm trying to generate the keystore file,

Does anyone know how to open and sign an apk file in eclipse on a mac?

I'm thinking i'll have to run phonegap locally some how?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

If you've built the APK outside of Eclipse, you can sign it on the command line using the Jarsigner tool, as described [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signapp) in the Android developer documentation.

`$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore
my_application.apk alias_name`

Where `my-release-key.keystore` is the path to your keystore, `my_application.apk` is the path to your APK, and `alias_name` is the name of the alias you gave the release signing key in your keystore.

Depending on whether you set up a password on your keystore and the signing key within it, you may need to add the flags `-storepass mystorepass` and `-keypass mykeypass`.

Comment: how do i create the keystone? i've been trying,$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore /Users/nathanielharman/Desktop/androidKeys /Users/nathaniel/harman/Desktop/LiveFire_Stoneplace-debug.apk -alias jqueryRef -keyalg RSA -validity 10000

Comment: That looks almost right - is 'jqueryRef' the alias (name of the key) you want to give it? And you're trying to create the keystore as LiveFire_Stoneplace-debug.apk, which isn't right (I presume this is the APK you're trying to sign). You need to change that to something like 'my-release-key.keystore' or similar. I'd recommend reading the whole page on Signing Your Application - there's lots we haven't covered here (such as the fact your private key can never change if you want updates to work): http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signapp

Comment: hey, thanks having a bit of a problem now getting phone gap working on my mac. anyway do you mean i need to change the file name of my .apk file?

Comment: No - you need to do two separate things. Create a key & keystore (that's the keytool -genkey... bit) - this has nothing to do with the APK, you should be creating a my-keystore.keystore file (it looks like currently you're trying to write to your APK file). Then, you need to sign the APK (that's the jarsigner bit).